# Vuex action can't access property value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I can't seem to pass data to my Vuex action. I always get the error message `TypeError: can't access property x, data is undefined`. I have done a few different approaches on passing property value but I couldn't make it work. Can you look at my code, what am I doing wrong?

**Store:**

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    announcements: []
  },
  getters: {},
  actions: {
    createAnnouncement({ commit }, courseId, data) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
        .post(`teacher/courses/announcements/create/${courseId}`, { title: data.title, message: data.message })
        .then((response) => {
          commit('ADD_ANNOUNCEMENT', response.data.data)
          resolve(response)
        })
        .catch((error) => { reject(error) })
      })
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    ADD_ANNOUNCEMENT(state, newAnnouncement) {
      state.announcements.push(newAnnouncement)
    }
  }
}
```

**Component:**

```
<script>
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: '',
      message: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('courses', ['getCourseData'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('announcements', ['createAnnouncement']),
    onSubmit() {
      const { announcementTitle, announcementMessage } = this
      const courseId = this.getCourseData.id
      this.createAnnouncement(courseId, { title: announcementTitle, message: announcementMessage }) 
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the best way to go about fixing my issue if I need two arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Actions only accept two arguments, the *context* and an optional *payload*.

Try changing your action to

```js
createAnnouncement({ commit }, { courseId, data }) {
  //...
}
```

and dispatch it with

```js
const payload = {
  courseId: this.getCourseData.id,
  data: {
    title: this.announcementTitle,
    message: this.announcementMessage
  }
}
this.createAnnouncement(payload)
```

See https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#actions

Comment: It worked thank you! I didn't know that actions only accept two arguments. I am new to VueJs/Vuex and still trying to learn.

Comment: @LAZYASSKID no problem. The Vuex guide can be a bit obscure sometimes. I've linked the API docs which should make it clearer